# Is it possible to install qt4 without installing qt4-doc?

Tags: package-management, qt

I am compiling a software from source (bibletime 2.9.2) and among the requirements is Qt4.5+. I found a way to do that by installing all the required packages at a tutorial at http://eyemeansit.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/compiling-bibletime-2-9-2-in-linux-mint-15/ and started the installation process.

I have a VERY slow internet connection hence every byte downloaded counts. I saw that the qt4-doc package is 96.8MB which being a documentation, I don't really need and it will take several hours to download fully. In comes the question - Is it possible to install qt4 without installing qt4-doc or maybe even the demos? I have no plans of developing in qt4.

Here's the original command (I have removed some packages to save on space):
`sudo apt-get install qt4-designer qt4-demos qt4-doc qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev`

After removing 'qt4-doc' from that command and pressing enter, it reads the package lists and then is added back to the 'The following extra packages will be installed:' category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure `apt` not to install the recommended packages by the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

And of course you don't need to install `qt4-doc` and `qt4-demos` just to develop. So the command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends qt4-designer qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanxs alot.